# Mysql using only a time in date_sub or alternative

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql field set as "TIME", and I would like to check against that time, using time as well.

I will have a cron run every 10 minutes, where my clients can set reminder messages to be sent out every day at any time of the day or so.

Using the following query does not give me the fields that are from the last 9 minutes:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `sms_reminders` WHERE (`option` = "weekdays" OR `option_days` LIKE "%4%") AND `time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 MINUTE)
```

However, this is giving me mixed results.

My `time` field is set at 09:50:00 (Time of running the query is 09:53:00).

Thanks.

Comment: `time` field should be compared with 'time'. So cast the value before checking. `\`time\` < TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 MINUTE))`

Comment: SELECT `id` FROM `sms_reminders` WHERE (`option` = "weekdays" OR `option_days` LIKE "%4%") AND `time` < (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 MINUTE))

Comment: `SELECT id FROM kwikwap_sms_reminders WHERE (option = "weekdays" OR option_days LIKE "%4%") AND time < TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 MINUTE))`

I set `time` to 10:00:00 and ran the query at 10:08:00. Did not give me any result back.

Comment: @kushalsuthar - Having 11,000 clients, each loading there reminders, can lead to a huge sms_reminders table to loop through, thus i would like to only select for that specific time.

Comment: @user3333166 `>` use this instead of `<`

Comment: @kushalsuthar - see my response, already figured that one. Add an answer and ill upvote..

Comment: @user3333166 I post my answer, Actually we both got answer at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make few changes in your code  use `>` this instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

After altering the query, I flipped the `<` to `>` and it is now working.